# Tag Nuke Request: [cal]

Tags: discussion

[[cal]](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cal) has 15 questions, 10 of which are closed.

Edit and remove to let die, or kill it outright?

Comment: I spotted 2 questions where it's probably a legit tag

Comment: And here I thought, "Wow, there are enough people having issues with cal(1) that they've submitted 15 questions on it?  It only has six options!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag is fine, there are questions that u[se it correctly](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bcal%5D%20closed:0) which haven't and are unlikely to be, closed. It's quite possible that more good questions will use it in the future.

Comment: Especially as wrong questions now tend to get jumped on and closed pretty quickly.